# Java return doesn't output message

Tags: java, methods, return

Question number : I don't understand why when I call this method in main(), it won't output the calculated average. The compiler leaves a blank and that is it. Self-learning Java is challenging.

Question number 2: can we output something like ("The average is" + median) using 'return' statement instead of 'System.out.print' ?

Thanks!

```
public static double calcAverage(int[] numbers){        // semi-done
    //    Calculate the average value and return it
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        total = total + numbers[i];
    }
    System.out.printf(" The average of all numbers is: \n", total/numbers.length);
    System.out.println();
    return total/numbers.length;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a `return` statement should output anything?

Comment: Use this instead: `System.out.println(" The average of all numbers is: \n" + total / numbers.length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, your `calcAverage` method **returns** a double, which isn't the same as printing it.

The following code shows the difference :

```
int[] list = { 1, 2, ..., 5};
calcAverage(list); // We did nothing with the return value... so we lost it
double avg = calcAverage(list); // We assigned the result.. did not lost it :)
// Now we can print the result
System.out.println("The average of all numbers is: \n" + avg);
System.out.println("The average of all numbers is: \n" + calcAverage(list)); // Or printing the result value directly
```

For your second question, if you want your method to return something like "The average is" + median, you will need a string as return value. But I don't think one would like his `calcAverage` method returning a string... *(Take a look at the code above which calls the procedure, stores the result and print it all)*

For example :

```
public static String calcAverage(int[] numbers){        // Returns a string
    //    Calculate the average value and return it
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
         total = total + numbers[i];
    }

    String answer = "The average of all numbers is: \n" + (total / numbers.length);
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go through the [Oracle Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) tutorial.

1. `System.out.printf()` -> indicates composed of literals and format specifiers. Arguments are required only if there are format specifiers in the format string. Eventually you can use there as `System.out.print()`.
2. Your method **return** type is **double** -> `public static double calcAverage(int[] numbers)`. So this method always return **double**. It will never return any other type like int, String etc. If it is not changed. If you want to return something like `The average is" + median`, means your **method** return type would be `String`, just print the resulted value. Then you need to change the following as `public static String calcAverage(int[] numbers)`

Answer (score 1):

1) You haven't told `printf` where or how to write the result. Try `System.out.printf(" The average of all numbers is: %f\n", total/numbers.length); //possibly "lf", I'm not a regular Java printf user.`

2) You can make your method return a `string` instead of a `double` - There are classes to help like `StringBuffer`.